# Delete duplicate words in array with sentences in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have a string array with words and sentences included.

For example:

```
array("dog","cat","the dog is running","some other text","some","text")
```

And I want to remove duplicate words, leaving only unique words in it. I want to remove these words even in sentences.

The result should look like:

```
array("dog","cat","the is running","other","some","text")
```

I tried the `array_unique` function but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are your requirements for which duplicates should be removed? It appears that you prefer to keep single words over the ones in sentences, but clarification would be helpful.

Comment: What would the output look like if the first and third element from your input array would be switched?

Comment: yes i would like to keep single words in the array that are unique.

Comment: Another follow-up: is `" "` your only word delimiter? All content is either alphabetical or a single space?

Comment: there are only " " in my array if there are sentences

Comment: @forprogramming777 - did my post helped you? did it solve your problem?

Comment: @dWinder thanks mate!! exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `array_unique` after loop with explode and `array_push`:

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $e) {
    array_push($res, ...explode(" ", $e));
}
print_r(array_unique($res));
```

Reference: 
[array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [array-unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/VWAIM)

If you want to keep the sentences use:

```
$arr = array("dog","cat","the dog is running","some other text","some","text");

// sort first to get the shortest sentence first
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {return count(explode(" ", $a)) - count(explode(" ", $b)); });

$words = [];
foreach($arr as &$e) {
    $res[] = trim(strtr($e, $words)); //get the word after swapping existing
    foreach(explode(" ", $e) as $w)
        $words[$w] =''; //add all new words to the swapping array with value of empty string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not pretty, but should get the job done and meet some of the edge cases at hand. I'm assuming that no more than one space separates words in a sentence string and that you want to preserve original ordering.

The approach is to walk the array twice, once to filter out duplicate single words, then once again to filter out duplicate words in sentences. This guarantees priority for single words. Finally, `ksort` the array (this is the ugly part from a time complexity standpoint: everything is `O(max_len_sentence * n)` up until now).

```
$arr = ["dog","cat","the dog is running","some other text","some","text"];
$seen = [];
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $i => $e) {
    if (preg_match("/^\w+$/", $e) && 
        !array_key_exists($e, $seen)) {
        $result[$i] = $e;
        $seen[$e] = 1;
    }
}

foreach ($arr as $i => $e) {
    $words = explode(" ", $e);

    if (count($words) > 1) {
        $filtered = [];

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            if (!array_key_exists($word, $seen)) {
                $seen[$word] = 0;
            }

            if (++$seen[$word] < 2) {
                $filtered[]= $word;
            }
        } 

        if ($filtered) {
            $result[$i] = implode($filtered, " ");
        }
    }
}

ksort($result);
$result = array_values($result);
print_r($result);
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => dog
    [1] => cat
    [2] => the is running
    [3] => other
    [4] => some
    [5] => text
)
```